# Why am I loosing 9 values in this pandas dataframe assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to update some numeric columns in my original dataframe (df) with newly standardized values (ndf2). There are **333 rows of non-null values**. After the assignment, 9 of my numeric values are NaN - I suspect my *assignment operation* is at fault or some issue with *indexing*? How do I do this correctly?

```
ndf2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 333 entries, 0 to 332
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   bill_length_mm     333 non-null    float64
 1   bill_depth_mm      333 non-null    float64
 2   flipper_length_mm  333 non-null    float64
 3   body_mass_g        333 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 10.5 KB
```

and

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 333 entries, 0 to 343
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   species            333 non-null    object 
 1   island             333 non-null    object 
 2   bill_length_mm     333 non-null    float64
 3   bill_depth_mm      333 non-null    float64
 4   flipper_length_mm  333 non-null    float64
 5   body_mass_g        333 non-null    float64
 6   sex                333 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 20.8+ KB
```

This is where the problems is - but not sure how to do this properly

```
df.iloc[:,2:-1] = ndf2  # is this the best way to do this?
```

because after this:

```
df.info(), df.shape

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 333 entries, 0 to 343
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   species            333 non-null    object 
 1   island             333 non-null    object 
 2   bill_length_mm     324 non-null    float64
 3   bill_depth_mm      324 non-null    float64
 4   flipper_length_mm  324 non-null    float64
 5   body_mass_g        324 non-null    float64
 6   sex                333 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 20.8+ KB
(None, (333, 7))
```

I am left with 324 numeric non-null values. I'm also confused about the different ranges reported by both dataframes `Int64Index: 333 entries, 0 to 343` and `Int64Index: 333 entries, 0 to 343`.

The dataset started out with 344 entries originally, but after

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

it went down to 333 as I would have expected.

---

**Update**:  It seems if I do `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`, this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that your indices are not aligned. You can check this with:

```
df1.index.equals(ndf2.index)
```

If they are not you can reset index by:

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
ndf2.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Afterwards, assign the values:

```
df[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']] = \
ndf2[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']]
```

Or alternatively the following should work without the indices alignment if your datasets have the same number of rows:

```
df[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']] = \
ndf2[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm', 'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g']].to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems if I do `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`, this fixes the problem since I'm only deleting items form this dataframe. Is there something wrong with the assignments I show above `df.iloc[:,2:-1] = ndf2 ` as it seems more concise than your version. Useful tip about checking the index values.

Comment: No, you're right - the iloc assignment is perfectly correct and indeed more concise.

Comment: @Levon try `df.update(ndf2)` for updating inplace or `df.assign(**ndf2)` for a copy of the dataframe,  so you dont have to worry about column name positions. That is after you have resetted the index.